# Determine the converse for a corollary

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logic

I am attempting to determine the converse of the following corollary found in Lebl's basic analysis:

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $c$ be a cluster point of $S$. Let $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function and suppose the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $c$ exists. Then

$$
lim_{x\to c} |f(x)| = |lim_{x\to c} f(x) |
$$

It has been quite some time since I've done analysis and mathematical proofs. I know that if I have the statement $P\to Q$ then its converse is $Q \to P$.

So I let the statement $P = $ "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $c$ exists." Which means the we can write the other statement as $Q = $ "$lim_{x\to c} |f(x)| = |lim_{x\to c} f(x) |$"

So the converse of the corollary must be something like:

Suppose $lim_{x\to c} |f(x)| = |lim_{x\to c} f(x) |$, then the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $c$ exists.

Please tell me if I've thought about this in the right way.

Comment: Is there an example of a function where the converse doesn't hold?

Comment: If we don't already know that the limit exists, how would you make sense of the right-hand side of that equality?

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking about, which is why I am asking this question. This all assumes I've gotten the converse statement correct. I can't think of any other possibility :/

Comment: This is not a statement of the form $P\to Q$, although it looks that way superficially. Your $Q$ rather *presupposes* that $P$ is true, in fact, it presupposes that both limits exist. Or, in other words, $Q$ is well-defined only if $P$ is true. This is a different kind of relation than simple implication. So there is no converse. You can rephrase into something like "if one limit exists then both exist and are equal", but then the converse is trivially valid: "if both limits exist and are equal then the first one exists". So "both limits exist and are equal if and only if the first one exists"

Comment: I appreciate the insight, I'll have to think about this a little more.